# How to display text saved in DB, properly in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am creating an application using *PHP* and *MySQL*.

***In the DB, the data is saved in the following manner:***

[image: DB-Data]

***But, while displaying the result in HTML page, the result comes like this:***

[image: HTML display]

The issue might be because HTML needs tags like `"<br/>"`, etc......

How can I display the result in actual format?

Here's the code section displaying the data:

```
<div class="com-text">
    <?php echo $row['chatDesc'];?>
</div>
```

### EDIT:

Also, I need to display the data by creating a div using jquery(dynamically). So how to display it in javascript format too?

```
html += '<div class="com-text">'+data.chat[i].chatDesc+'</div>';
$("#chat_list").append(html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should use nl2br which inserts line breaks where newlines occur in a string

the javascript equivement of this function + your code:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {   
  var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : 

  '<br>';    
  return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2');
}

html += '<div class="com-text">'+nl2br(data.chat[i].chatDesc, true)+'</div>';
$("#chat_list").append(html);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the below simple CSS

```
.com-text{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
      word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: good solution. saved my time. thnx mate

Answer (score 1):

use nl2br();

```
<div class="com-text">
    <?php echo nl2br($row['chatDesc']) ;?>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the best solution. [more info about nl2br function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<div class="com-text">
   <pre> <?php echo $row['chatDesc'];?> </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the **dog** now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

Answer (score 1):

You should use `nl2br` which inserts line breaks where newlines occur in a string

```
<div class="com-text">
    <?php echo nl2br($row['chatDesc']);?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `nl2br()` function to format it:

```
<?php

$mychat = nl2br($row['chatDesc']);

?>
```

Here is how you can do..

```
 <div class="com-text">
 <?php echo $mychat; ?>
 </div>
```